# Сортировка по count

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такая задача:

> Выведите список клиентов (имя, фамилия) и количество заказов данных клиентов, имеющих статус "new". Упорядочить по количеству заказов в порядке убывания.

Вот, что я написал:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, COUNT(st.id) as 'new_sale_num'
    FROM client as c
    INNER JOIN sale as s ON s.client_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN status as st ON st.id = s.status_id
    WHERE st.name = 'new';
```

Во-первых, такая запрос неправильный и выдает ошибку. Как его сделать правильным ? Во-вторых, как сгруппировать такой запрос по `new_sale_num` ? Просто `ORDER BY new_sale_num` добавить в конце ?

Ошибка:

> Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'store.c.first_name';

Я так понимаю, что писать `COUNT` в `SELECT` вместе с другим параметрами неправильно, т.к. `COUNT` считает все, а не некоторое значение для конкретных полей. Как же быть ?

Comment: ".. и выдает ошибку" - добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Да, просто `ORDER BY new_sale_num`. И зачем вы заключили new_sale_num в обычные апострофы, уберите их или поставьте обратные апострофы потому что _имена_ могут быть только в обратных

Comment: Добавил ошибку в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вот так будет работать

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, COUNT(s.status_id) as new_sale_num
FROM client as c
INNER JOIN sale as s ON s.client_id = c.id
WHERE st.name = 'new'
GROUP BY c.first_name, c.last_name
ORDER BY COUNT(s.status_id)
```

Если есть одинаковые ФИО с разними id тогда добавьте `c.id` в `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.first_name as [Имя], c.last_name as [Фамилия], COUNT(s.status_id) as [Кол-во]
FROM client
INNER JOIN sale ON sale.client_id = client.id
WHERE sale.name = 'new'
GROUP BY client.first_name, client.last_name
ORDER BY COUNT(sale.status_id)
```

Была еще ошибка тут `WHERE st.name = 'new'`, st - нету такой таблицы, есть только s)